# Bound on absolute value of expectation

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Let $X, Y$ be random variables, and $X$ positive and bounded ($0\leq X <C$ for some constant $C$).

Is it true that
$$\lvert E(XY)\rvert\leq c\lvert E(Y)\rvert$$
for some constant $c>0$? If yes, why?

**Comment**: I can only obtain that $\lvert E(XY)\rvert\leq C E\lvert Y\rvert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment contains a hint why the answer is "no".

If $X$ is a non-degenerate random variable, you  can find constants $a$ and $b$ so that $Y=aX+b$ obeys $E[XY]=1$ and $E[Y]=0$.  Then the only $c$ satisfying your inequality is $c=0$.